# How do I use PHP to get screen names of all my followers in twitter

Tags: php, twitter

I am new to using Twitter - API, how do I use PHP to get the screen names of all my followers in twitter ? which API do I need to use? please help...

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/docs What have you tried?

Comment: With that google really would have been an option.

Comment: I have got the Id's using
https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.xml?screen_name=example

how do I get the screenname of corresponding ID with out authentication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted from a [very similar post](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/581) from Twitter Developers:

> If you just need the user ids of the users you are following or who
>   follow you, then it's usually a single API call. If you need the
>   screen_names and other biographical data, you'll need to chain API
>   requests together.
>
> The methods you are looking for are:
>
> - [GET friends/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids) and [GET followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids) for getting the ids
> - [GET users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) to "hydrate" the user_ids into full user objects

Comment: how do I get only the screenname of corresponding ID as a response with out authentication ?

Comment: I think that you can use GET users/lookup (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup). You just need to pass an array of ids (max 100).